# In auth0 lock, how to refresh the id_token?

Tags: auth0

I am building a cordova mobile app and trying to use the auth0 lock API. I am having trouble with the refresh token. I can retreive the refresh token in the authResult but cannot figure out how to actually refresh the id_token ( I suppose i could write the REST calsl myself )

In the v9 docs, it seems there used to be a method: https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/v9/using-a-refresh-token

```
lock.getClient().refreshToken(refresh_token, function (err, delegationResult) {
  // Get here the new JWT via delegationResult.id_token
});
```

However in lock v10 it seems this method doesn't exist any more: https://auth0.com/docs/libraries/lock/v10/api

Can anyone advise if there is a way to refresh the token using the lock API?

Comment: You can initialize an instance of Auth0.js the `.getClient()` method will return the Auth0js object which Lock uses, with Lock 10 we advice you to create an Auth0.js instance seperately.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to either have included Auth0's script tag in your HTML:

```
 <script src="https://cdn.auth0.com/js/lock/10.8/lock.min.js"></script>
```

Or, if you've installed from npm, you can require Auth0:

```
 var Auth0 = require("auth0-js");
```

---

In V10, you create an instance of the Auth0 client (separate from the Auth0Lock instance) which has a function `refreshToken()`:

```
var auth0 = new Auth0({clientID: YOUR_CLIENT_ID, domain: YOUR_AUTH0_DOMAIN});
...
auth0.refreshToken(refresh_token_here, (err, resp) => {
    // resp: {expires_in: 36000, id_token: "id_token here", token_type: "Bearer"}
}
```

The same can also be achieved by using the `getDelegationToken()` function:

```
auth0.getDelegationToken({
    client_id: YOUR_CLIENT_ID,
    grant_type: "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer",
    refresh_token: refresh_token_here,
    scope: "openid",
    api_type: "auth0"
  }, (err, resp) => {
    // resp: {expires_in: 36000, id_token: "id_token here", token_type: "Bearer"}
  });
```

Comment: it would be helpful if you show how to import Auth0 separately.

Comment: How can you obtain the value of `refresh_token`?

Comment: @KeesdeKooter To obtain a refresh token, you need to include the 'offline_access' scope when initiating an authentication request. The response will then include a refresh_token value. Auth0's documentation covers that pretty well [here](https://auth0.com/docs/tokens/refresh-token/current).